# Triangle in CSS inside a box

Tags: html, css, geometry, css-shapes

Well I don't know how to explain it correctly. Here, check this screenshot which has what I want to make. My designer gave me this. If I don't find a solution i'll use images and no code. Is it possible to do this with CSS3?

[Here is the image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wf1h0a27c76nnnb/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-05%20at%206.49.20%20PM.png)

[image]

See the triangle inside that box? I want to do this. Thank you!

Comment: It's possible, but not terribly pretty... I'll go hack something.

Comment: I'm voting a reopen on this question - if this kind of question isn't allowed we can't have **any** "how do I achieve complex effect X in CSS" questions whatsoever whilst these are often the interesting ones to discover tricks like I demonstrated below. If you don't know `border` works like this in corners you'll never think of it yourself.

Comment: you may also check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-css-arrow-triangle-over-an-image

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creative use of borders to achieve this effect, no images were harmed in the following sample and you can even set the position of the arrow on the element itself - becomes more straightforward if you can hardcode it for your design.

*HTML*

```
<div class="top">
    <span class="arrow" style="left:40%"></span>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.top {
    background:url(http://blog.positscience.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/ice-cream3.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #888;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.arrow {
    border:30px solid #aaa;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-color:transparent #aaa transparent #aaa;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.arrow:before, .arrow:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:5000px;
    bottom:0;
    height:30px;
    background:#aaa;
}
.arrow:before {
    right:30px;
}
.arrow:after {
    left:30px;
}
```

[Working JSfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rrz2m/).

[Or the full integrated sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/rrz2m/2/).

Comment: +1 worked as a charm! you are great!